# Access Denied of a folder on a Drive

Tags: windows-7, security

I wanted to restrict access of other people in a certain drive of my computer. What I did was go to the Security Tab (under Drive Properties) and remove the All Users entry. My account is an administrator account. I left only Systems and Administrator on the list. However, when I tried to access drive D, I got an Access Denied error, and Security Tab is already missing.i resolved the problem using safe mode way but i got another problem, I'd  used command prompt to hide(attrib) a folder in drive D but i can't access it, though i can access all other files. I used cmd to unhide but access denied

Answer (score 1):

Windows has both a group called Administrators and a default user called Administrator. If you took away rights to the Administrators group but left the user Administrator then the user you are logging in has no rights to that drive. That said, you can solve the problem with the 'hidden' folder by either going into safe mode and assigning permissions to either the user directly or any group he member of, or as administrator take ownership of the folder which will then allow you to change the ACL.

You should be able to take ownership in 'normal' mode as long as you are admin on the box.